# SPARQL to get wikipedia link of resources URIs uri1 and uri2 in DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

In a document I read a piece of information as follows:

> Ranker does not use only external information sources but exploits also further
>   information from the original DBpedia dataset. In fact, we also consider
>   Wikipedia hypertextual links mapped in DBpedia by the property dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink.
>   Whenever in a Wikipedia document w1 there is a hypertextual link to another
>   Wikipedia document w2, in DBpedia there is a dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink
>   from uri1 to uri2. Hence, if there is a dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink from
>   uri1 to uri2 and/or vice versa, we assume a stronger relation between the two resources. We evaluate the strength of the connection as follow:

[WikiS(uri1, uri2) Algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJgoD.png)

But I have tried searching for properties wikilink on dbpedia but no results. I tried the following query:

```
Query 1: 
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix dbpprop: <http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/instances/synset-movie-noun-1>
select count(?s)
where{
   ?s ?p ?o .
   FILTER(?p, dbpprop:wikilink)
}

Query 2:
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix dbpprop: <http://www.w3.org/2006/03/wn/wn20/instances/synset-movie-noun-1>
select count(?s)
where{
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER(?p = dbpedia-owl:wikiPageWikiLink)
}

Query 3:
select *
where{
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER regex(?p, "link")
}
```

But no results.

How I can install algorithms WikiS (uri1, uri2) on in my program.

Thank so much.

Comment: your prefix `dbpprop` is strange as 1) its not the common DBpedia prefix and 2) either `/` or `#` is missing at the end.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50171855/7879193

Answer (score 3):

Get all object properties that contain the token "link" in its URI:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?p WHERE {
  ?p  a <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty>
  FILTER regex(?p, "link", "i")
}
```

returns

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                           p                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/linkedTo                  |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/provinceLink              |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageEditLink          |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageHistoryLink       |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageInterLanguageLink |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRevisionLink      |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLinkText      |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageWikiLink          |
| http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageExternalLink      |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

The same but with its frequencies:

```
SELECT  ?p (count(*) AS ?cnt)
WHERE
  { { SELECT DISTINCT  ?p
      WHERE
        { ?p  a                     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty>
          FILTER regex(?p, "link", "i")
        }
    }
    ?s  ?p  ?o
  }
GROUP BY ?p
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to voted you but i not enough reputation.